# SonarQube - How to change severity of mulitple rules in bulk

Tags: sonarqube

I want to change the severity of mulitple rules in a quality profile in bulk. At the moment there are ca. 20 rules with "Blocker" severity and I want to set them all to "Critical". Because we created a new quality gate for blocker rule violations and this rules should not be included.

I could do this manually one by one. But I wonder if it's possible to do it in bulk. With 20 rules it's just annoying, with 100 rules changing the severity manually one by one would be a major headache.

There's an issue about this, [SONAR-3421 "Enhance Bulk Change possibilities for Profile Rule Filter"](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3421). The issues is closed now. But as far as I can tell, this functionalty has not been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do confirm that this is not possible to bulk change the severity of a set of rules activated in a Quality Profile (whereas this is possible to bulk change the severity of a set of issues). Even if this might be useful from time to time, there is no plan to implement such feature at short term.

Comment: It's a shame there's no such ability. I'm going to add StyleCop rules (170) and update Severity one by one :(

Answer (score 2):

work around is exporting the profile ==> notepad++ to bulk replace ==> restore profile